# 'makeCluster' not found (R)

Tags: r

I have downloaded the doSNOW package as well as the caret package but I am still receiving errors saying that some of the functions within these packages are not present. For example:

```
rpart.cv <- function(seed, training, labels, ctrl) {
    cl <- makeCluster(6, type = "SOCK")
    registerDoSNOW(cl)

    set.seed(seed)
    # Leverage formula interface for training
    rpart.cv <- train(x = training, y = labels, method = "rpart", tuneLength = 30, 
                trControl = ctrl)

    #Shutdown cluster
    stopCluster(cl)

    return (rpart.cv)
}
```

When I put a value into this code it returns an error stating that 'object makeCluster is not found.' What could be the problem?

```
    #Grab features 
    features <- c("Pclass", "Title", "family.size")
    rpart.train.1 <- data.combined[1:891, features]

    #Running cross validation 
    rpart.1.cv.1 <- rpart.cv(94622, rpart.train.1, rf.label, ctrl.3)
    rpart.1.cv.1
```

Comment: Did you load the package? `library("doSNOW")`

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Yes, I've loaded both packages, but it still isn't working.

Comment: `makeCluster()` is a function from **parallel** https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/parallel/versions/3.6.2/topics/makeCluster

Comment: I managed to sort it out, thanks for your help!